# In how many ways we can can split $20$ same fruits and $15$ same sandwiches to $5$ children?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I would like to ask, in how many ways we can can split $20$ same fruits and $15$ same sandwiches to $5$ children?

The solution says its $24C4 \cdot 19C4$, but I can't understand why.

I would also like to ask why aren't here used combinations with repetition  and when are they actually useful (with a simple example if possible) and why is the word "same" here so important.

Comment: This is a combinations with repetition problem since you are distributing identical objects to distinct boxes.  In fact, the solution is found by solving two combinations with repetitions problem, one for the fruit and one for the sandwiches, then multiplying the results.

Answer (score 1):

There are
$$
\binom{20+5-1}{5-1}
$$
ways to distribute the $20$ identical fruits to the 5 children and 
$$
\binom{15+5-1}{5-1}
$$
ways to distribute the $15$ identical sandwiches to the $5$ children. Both of these results may be obtained using [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)). The product rule yields the result.

Comment: How to know when is this rule used and why in my case aren't used combinations with repetition?

Answer (score 1):

> In how many ways can $20$ identical pieces of fruit and $15$ identical sandwiches be distributed to $5$ children?

Let $x_j$ be the number of pieces of fruit distributed to the $j$th child, $1 \leq j \leq 5$.  Then 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 = 20 \tag{1}$$
Equation 1 is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation 1 corresponds to the placement of four addition signs in a row of twenty ones.  For instance, 
$$1 1 1 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 + + 1 1 1 1 + 1 1 1 1 1 1$$
corresponds to the solution $x_1 = 7$, $x_2 = 3$, $x_3 = 0$, $x_4 = 4$, and $x_5 = 6$.  Therefore, the number of solutions of equation 1 in the nonnegative integers is the number of ways we can insert four addition signs in a row of twenty ones, which is 
$$\binom{20 + 4}{4} = \binom{24}{4}$$
since we must decide which four of the twenty-four positions required for twenty ones and four addition signs will be filled with addition signs.

Since a particular solution of the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_k = n \tag{2}$$
in the nonnegative integers corresponds to the placement of $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $n$ ones, the number of solutions of equation 2 in the nonnegative integers is 
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$
since we must select which of the $n + k - 1$ positions required for $n$ ones and $k - 1$ addition signs will be filled with addition signs.  Alternatively, we could select which $n$ of the $n + k - 1$ positions will be filled with ones, so equation 2 has 
$$\binom{n + k - 1}{n} = \binom{n + k - 1}{k - 1}$$
solutions.

Judging by your remarks in the comments, you used the formula $\binom{n + k - 1}{\color{red}{k}}$, which is incorrect.

Let $y_j$ be the number of sandwiches distributed to the $j$th child, $1 \leq j \leq 5$.  Then 
$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 = 15 \tag{3}$$
Equation 3 is an equation in the nonnegative integers with 
$$\binom{15 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{19}{4}$$
solutions.

By the Multiplication Principle, the number of ways we can distribute $20$ pieces of fruit and $15$ sandwiches to five children is 
$$\binom{24}{4}\binom{19}{4}$$

> Why is the word same or identical important?

Let's focus on the pieces of fruit.  If each piece of fruit were considered different, then it would matter which piece of fruit is distributed to which child.  Since there are five ways to distribute each of the twenty pieces of fruit, there would be $5^{20}$ ways to distribute $20$ different pieces of fruit to five children.

By treating the pieces of fruit as identical, what matters is how many pieces of fruit are distributed to each child.

> Combinations with Repetition

In a combination with repetition problem, $n$ objects are selected from $k$ types of objects.  Assuming there are at least $n$ objects of each type, the number of ways this can be done is the number of solutions of the equation 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_k = n$$
in the nonnegative integers, where $x_j$, $1 \leq j \leq k$, is the number of objects of type $j$.

**Example.**  A fruit basket containing $12$ pieces of fruit is to be assembled using apples, bananas, melons, oranges, and pears.  Assuming at least $12$ pieces of each type of fruit are available, in how many ways can the fruit basket be filled?

*Solution.*  Let $x_a$ denote the number of apples selected; let $x_b$ denote the number of bananas selected; let $x_m$ denote the number of melons selected; let $x_o$ denote the number of oranges selected; let $x_p$ denote the number of pears selected.  Then the number of ways the fruit basket can be filled is the number of solutions of the equation
$$x_a + x_b + x_m + x_o + x_p = 12$$
in the nonnegative integers, which is 
$$\binom{12 + 5 - 1}{5 - 1} = \binom{16}{4}$$

**Note.**  Observe that the problem of distributing $n$ identical objects to $k$ distinct boxes is equivalent to selecting $n$ objects from $k$ types of objects if there at least $n$ of each type available since both problems reduce to solving the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + \ldots + x_k = n$$
in the nonnegative integers.

Comment: Thank you for explanation